# Google DataFlow & Reading Parquet files

Tags: avro, google-cloud-dataflow, parquet, apache-beam

Trying to use Google DataFlow Java SDK but for my usecases my input files are .parquet files.

Couldn't find any out-of-the-box functionality to read parquet into DataFlow pipeline as Bounded data source.
As i understand i can create a coder and/or sink a bit like AvroIO based on [Parquet Reader](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetReader.java).

Did anyone can advise how the best way to implement it? or point me to a reference with How-to \ examples?

Appreciate your help!

--A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find progress towards ParquetIO (out of the box functinonality as you called it) at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-214.

In the meantime, it should be possible to read Parquet files using Hadoop FileInputFormat in both [Beam](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop) and [Dataflow SDKs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/tree/master/contrib/hadoop).